# How can I make a Cocoa window which appears on top of fullscreen windows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to make a "full screen overlay window" in a program for OS X. Precisely, the window must at all times be on top of all other windows, including on top of the menu bar in non-maximized-window spaces, and on top of maximized windows in their own spaces, and on top during Exposé. It must not participate in "change space" animations; i.e., its position must be fixed relative to the physical screen at all times. (The window will be semi-transparent and will ignore mouse events, but I know how to do this already.)

How do I achieve this "overlay window" behavior? I have got this far:

- I should set the `window.level` to `CGWindowLevelKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)` so that it is always on top of other windows in the same space.
- I should set `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary` so that the window stays in place during Exposé.

What I don't know is how to keep this behavior when switching spaces. I thought I should set `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces`, but its behavior has two problems:

- The window does not appear on top of other fullscreen windows.
- The window is *duplicated* on every space, rather than staying in the same place on top of all spaces. This is important because of the space-switch animation.

[I have heard that an `NSPanel` would help me](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/iterm2-discuss/ECQl7oBy3a4/BVYWkB24pywJ), but I have not been able to make this work, either.

In short, **Can a window appear on top of a fullscreen window in OS X? Can you provide a short, full example?**

Comment: I don't suppose you've found an answer for this? I also have a need to display a window on top of another app's full-screen window.

Comment: @MarkBessey I did actually find a solution, using `NSPanel`. I'll try to answer the question with some sample code when I have a moment

Comment: @jameshfisher Can you share your solution? I have a similar problem, and I have tried what you mentioned in the description but unfortunately they don't work.

Comment: @jameshfisher would you mind sharing your solution if you are available, I really need it.

Comment: Another quick bump, anyone solved this one yet?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `window.level = CGWindowLevelForKey(.MaximumWindowLevelKey)`.

I can't help you with the spaces part.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I was already doing that -- sorry for being unclear. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, it work ok.

```
NSPanel *test_panel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(300, 300, 500, 500) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[test_panel setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
[test_panel setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];
[test_panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[test_panel setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
[test_panel setLevel:kCGMainMenuWindowLevel-1];
[test_panel  setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
[test_panel setCanBeVisibleOnAllSpaces:YES];
[test_panel center];
[test_panel orderFront:nil];
```